# Erro ao tentar adicionar um fragment a um projeto no android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Criei um projeto e não coloquei nada nele, o mesmo está zerado, somente com aquela textView "Hello World". O problema apareceu quando tentei adicionar um fragment (with a + 1 button) ao projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já dei refresh e nada. Quando tento iniciar o app, dá isso no log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Não mudei nada tanto na activity inicial quanto no fragment, segue o código dos mesmos respectivamente:

```js
package genesysgeneration.frag;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```js
package genesysgeneration.frag;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton;

/**
 * A fragment with a Google +1 button.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link One.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link One#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class One extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    // The request code must be 0 or greater.
    private static final int PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    // The URL to +1.  Must be a valid URL.
    private final String PLUS_ONE_URL = "http://developer.android.com";
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public One() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment One.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static One newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        One fragment = new One();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        //Find the +1 button
        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
        mPlusOneButton.initialize(PLUS_ONE_URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: tente adicionar o  `multiDexEnabled true` no grandle.

Comment: continua dando erro no log

Comment: Olha essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34284213/2570426

Comment: Houve progresso, não impediu a inicialização, o log não apresentou nada a princípio, porém o app unfortunately has sttoped.